# Alias to custom path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, godaddy-api, aws-application-load-balancer

I have AWS ELB DNS name(Testing-QA-7849049.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com)

which has routing configured based on path

eg : Testing-QA-7849049.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/qa/index.html ---> will point to qa server 
     Testing-QA-7849049.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/qa1/index.html --> will point to qa1 server

Now i want my custome domain to be alias for this name .

eg :

Testing-QA-7849049.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/qa/index.html ---> mydomain/index.html

how can i achieve this . Go daddy doesn't allow  / in point to field .

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this using DNS name, only using IP for this resource. To achieve this you need to have 3rd party resource linked to AWS through AWS Direct Connect or a VPN connection.
Application Load Balancer [supports only instance, IP or Lambda as target types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-type). You will use IP of connected 3rd party resource here.

This is complicated but this is a sign your approach is not a solution to the problem you have.

> Now i want my custome domain to be alias for this name .

You need to have DNS resolution before Load Balancer on communication scheme. For example instead of **"Testing-QA-7849049.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/qa/index.html ---> mydomain/index.html"** you should have **"mydomain/index.html ---> will point to qa server"** in your terminology.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a path level mapping such as "/index.html" using dns records.

#### Approach 1 - using subdomains for each environment

You can instead create cnames to point to the dns name of the load balancer.

create a cname called `qa1.mydomain.com` and point it to `Testing-QA-7849049.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com`. Then you can access the index.html through https://qa1.mydomain.com/qa1/index.html

you can similarly set up a `qa.mydomain.com`

#### Approach 2 - Use Path-Based Routing with Your Application Load Balancer

In this method, you create one load balancer to manage both environments such as `qa` and `qa1`.

Then you create two targets , one for each environments.

After that you can configure the `routing` in the load balancer to forward any url that starts with `qa/*` to a target group.

Similarly forward the path matches `qa1/*` to the second target group.

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html

Comment: Updated the answer, may be the approach two is close to what you are after